# pandas merge quantity how do solve?

Tags: pandas, merge

A

```
    |Key1|Key2|Gender|
    |1234|5678|Male  |
    |1234|5678|Female|
    |0000|1111|Male  |
    |0000|1111|Female|
```

B

```
|Key1|Key2|Number|
|1234|5678|100   |
|0000|1111|500   |
```

df= pd.merge(A, B, on=['key1', 'key2'], how='outer') produces below for merging.

```
|Key1|Key2|Gender|Number|
|1234|5678|Male  |100   |
|1234|5678|Female|100   |
|0000|1111|Male  |500   |
|0000|1111|Female|500   |
```

However , I am looking for below , where row 1 and 2 share 100 ,row 3 and 4 share 500 in number. This could be easily done using excel , but how to do it using pandas.

```
|Key1|Key2|Gender|Number                   |
|1234|5678|Male  |100, shared with row 2   |
|1234|5678|Female|                         |
|0000|1111|Male  |500, shared with row 4   |
|0000|1111|Female|                         |
```

In actual dataset , take note there are over 10 columns like the column 'Number' to be merged.

*Apologies , I have corrected the above , i would like to clarify that there are not duplicates , just rows with the same common keys (key1 and key2)

Comment: What does "share" mean? Does only the first row receive the 100?

Comment: no , meaning both row 1 and row 2 collectively receive100 . Same goes for row 3 and  4 share the total amount 500. Many thanks. I was told i could park column 'Number' under index to produce a merged cells where key1 and key 2 are the same . However , can I do it for over 10 'Number' like columns

Comment: So how is the amount going to be distributed? Evenly, randomly, some kind of weightings?

Comment: kindly share the code u would use in excel

Comment: both row 1 and 2 cumulatively share 100 , distribution has not been done yet , distribution is to be done later on during the optimization stage. For now , i cant break these into 2 tables , as i would need to present this dashboard

Comment: hi @sammywemmy, i dont use codes for excel, just drag and toggle when it comes to merging , done manually . Basically , the logic is that rows with common keys should share the same cell content for column 'Number'